# Convert dataset datatables into IList<DataTable> type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataset which contains multiple datatables. Now i want to copy over these datatable into IList object.

```
var tables = new[] { DT1, DT2 };   //I want to change this line of code to pull the datatables from the dataset.
bool test = Funx(tables);

private bool Funx(IList<DataTable> tbls)
{
   ///some operation..
}
```

But in my case the dataset could contain any number of datatables. How can i prepare tables var object with all datatable from the dataset.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Cast` + `ToList`:

```
IList<DataTable> tables = dataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().ToList();
```

You need to use `Enumerable.Cast` since [`DataTableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(returned by [`Tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<DataTable>` (the class is old):